# How do I connect to an Ubuntu server via SSH from OSX?

Tags: macosx, openssh

I recently downloaded OpenSSH on my ubuntu server; though I don't have a domain name yet I do have another device (running OSX) on the same LAN as my server.

Is it possible to connect to the server? since both devices are on the same LAN, and osX already has an ssh client (terminal)?

If it's not possible, I would like to know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they are on the same LAN, it should be possible to connect using IPs.

The syntax for `ssh` is pretty simple. The minimum you need to specify is the target IP *or* hostname. The following are effectively the same for me:

```
ssh github.com
ssh 192.30.252.130
```

If you don't specify a username, your client's user is applied. So, for me, the above commands are the same as:

```
ssh muru@192.30.252.130
ssh -l muru 192.30.252.130
```

If you don't specify a port, 22 is assumed. So the first two commands are the same as:

```
ssh 192.30.252.130 -p 22
```

Unlike other programs, the `IP:port` syntax is not applicable here.

For everything else, there's the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/ssh.1.html).

This is all assuming that your client is similar to the OpenSSH client. For anything else, consult its manpage.

Comment: Sorry - I had misread the question to be 'how to connect' rather than 'is is possible'

Comment: Answering "how" would be great too :) I was checking some tutorials but the arguments for the connection are not very clear ; all the ones I read only use examples based on internet connection via domain name

Comment: @user1405097 A few details are needed for that: do you know how to look up your server's IP? Is SSH configured to run on the default port or something else?

Comment: @muru yes, I can fetch both external & internal ip (i don't have a static ip), the configuration for the ssh is default too. I already have a shell account too on my server -other than root- .

Comment: @muru thanks for the detailed answer ; I managed to connect to the server using both the direct local ip & the server's name on the network, I used the second syntax you provided, looking like this : " ssh guest0@MY-SERVER-IP ".